# GridSearchCV, representation of each class in each part of the dataframe

Tags: python, grid-search

I have to do a multiclass classification (3). I search the best parameter for my classifier with `GridSearchCV`.

But I have a imbalanced `x_train` (and `x_test`) : 3079 intances for 0, 12 for 1 and 121 for 3.

I have this error:

> Target is multiclass but `average='binary'`. Please choose another average setting.

I think that this error comes from the split, when we split the `x_train` we haven't got each class in each part. Have you a solution for each class represented in each part? Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

No, this is coming from your scoring function which you are passing into `GridSearchCV(....., scoring=SOME_METRIC... )`. Please show that part.

If its is one of these, and the classification task is multiclass, then they cannot work:

- 'f1'
- 'recall'
- 'precision'

Then you need to supply the `average` param.

So if you are using the below scoring currently:

```
GridSearchCV(....., scoring='f1'... )
```

Then you need to append one of 'micro', 'macro' or 'weighted' like this:

```
GridSearchCV(....., scoring='f1_micro'... )
```

Same for `precision` or `recall`

See this page for more details: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#the-scoring-parameter-defining-model-evaluation-rules

If you are using something else, please show the code.

Comment: this answer should be accepted as correct answer. Thank you Kumar